# A more complete auto-format in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2013, autoformatting

Of course you might immediately think "This question has been asked before!".

But it hasn't been answered.

All answers seem to suggest `Ctrl+K,D` or some variant will help me. I have looked quite a bit. `Ctrl-K,D` does lots of things for me and I use it all the time. But it falls short on the examples below.

I am currently using Visual Studio 2013.

Take this class:

```
public class RubbishAutoFormat
{
    public List<string> IsntThisRubbish { get; set; }
    public RubbishAutoFormat()
    {
        IsntThisRubbish = new List<string>
    {
        "Yes", "It", "Is"
    };
    }
}
```

I can hit `Ctrl+K,D` as many times as I like, but bugger all happens.

If I delete and re-enter the `;` at the end of the list initialiser, I get this loveliness:

```
public class RubbishAutoFormat
{
    public List<string> IsntThisRubbish { get; set; }
    public RubbishAutoFormat()
    {
        IsntThisRubbish = new List<string>
        {
            "Yes",
            "It",
            "Is"
        };
    }
}
```

If I have a big class with a lot of badly formatted code of this ilk, my only option at the moment is to categorically traipse through all of the relevant semi-colons and delete and retype them to trigger the correct "smart" auto-format in Visual Studio.

How can I make this happen for a whole document at a time? "Developer logic" in me stipulates: "It's already done for parts of the code, how do I trigger the loop for all of the code?" :)

Someone please! It's driving me crazy :)

Comment: http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/features/code_formatting.html

Comment: Thanks, good tip if you have ReSharper - although their documentation suggests a keyboard shortcut that is now mapped to another ReSharper function. Use `Ctrl+E, Ctrl+C`

Comment: It depends which keyboard scheme you're using. I use the classic scheme and the shortcut is Ctrl + Alt + F I think. If you've never tried Resharper you should give it a whirl - its amazing.

Comment: Yeah I use ReSharper, it's the closest I come to worshipping anything :) I use the Visual Studio scheme (not IntelliJ). Either way, your answer worked for me (thank you!) but I'd still love to know if there is a native way to tap into the power of formatting when you hit that `;` but document-wide :)